# Serve custom file based on user input

Tags: php, javascript

I want to make a website that will serve a custom file based on user input, for example lets say it's a story and it'll place your name in the text where there is a string variable designed for being swapped, but only for that one user. I've tried googling but I have absolutely no idea how to approach this and with what language and with what libraries etc.
Can someone point me in the right direction? I know a bit of python, even less of php and no javascript, but I'd be happy to learn a bit to get this to work.

Sorry if this is a little bit hard to understand, I'll rephrase it if I need to.

Comment: Please do rephrase. Post an example. Take your time to write the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I were making this, I would serve the username through a session variable. What this essentially is, is that you present the user with a textbox and ask them to input their name. Then, you would access this through the `$_SESSION` array when you want to say their name.

First, in every PHP file that you'll need to use their name in, at the very top, before any HTML, or anything is outputted, you want to use the function `session_start();`. This is fundamental, it must be called before anything is sent to the browser.

Next, you create your form with HTML. Here's an example, it's what I'll be using in this answer:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

That's it for the form, save it and create a new file. Call it `process.php`. In process.php, we will need to handle the user input. The bare minimum for this page should be:

```
<?php

session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") // Make sure the file is not being directly accessed
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    echo "Thank you, your username has been saved.";
}
```

Now you can use `$_SESSION['username']` anywhere in your script, as long as the user has inputted a name. For instance, you could do this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) // Make sure that the user has a name
{
    echo $_SESSION['username'] . " was walking down a dirt road..."; // Might output "Seabody was walking down a dirt road..." depending on the username.
}
```